# Selecting text from ajax success response don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to insert form data through ajax and then get the ROW id of inserted data in order to lead the user to a new URL where he/she could see the inserted data.

So I managed to make this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "controllers/clients.php",
                async: false,
                data: form_data,
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){           
                    var jqResponse = $(response);
                    var rowID = jqResponse.find('div#row').text();
                    console.log (rowID);
                }
            });
```

But (rowID) doesn't show nothing. The problem is that I have a Debug function and when Debug mode is activated it shows all query performed and some other things so if Debug mode isn't activated this isn't needed because there isn't any text.

I've logged both variables and in jqResponse I can see the following:

[image: Console of jQuery object]

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the .filter() instead the .find() selector, the last one may have some parent->children behaviour that makes your code not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to log the contents of `response` and `jqResponse` to see if they contain the selector you specified, and data within the selected element.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to fix there too. But I've tried it before. Following your advice, I've logged both variables and in jqResponse I can see the following: http://imgur.com/ffjfA

Comment: See the image, I'm updating the question too